# pyspark: filter parquet files with different column structures

Tags: pyspark, filter, apache-spark-sql, schema

I have my parquet data saved in aws s3 bucket. The parquet files are partitioned by date and the folder structure looks like

```
MyFolder
  |-- date=20210701
    |--part-xysdf-snappy.parquet
  |-- date=20210702
    |--part-fasdf-snappy.parquet
  |-- date=20210703
    |--part-ghdfg-snappy.parquet
 ....
 ....
```

Please note that **Parquet in date=20210701** (which is the earliest entry) is faulty and its missed two columns

```
  +-------+-----+
  |   name|grade|
  +-------+-----+
  |Alberto|  100|
  | Dakota|   96|
  +-------+-----+
```

The rest of parquet files are all good, which is like

```
  +-------+-----+------+-------+
  |   name|grade|height|  date |
  +-------+-----+--------------+
  |Karolin|  110|  173 |20210701
  | Lucas |   91|  178 |20210701
  +-------+-----+------+-------+
```

If I want to only focus on '**name**' and '**grade**', I can use the following code to show the results

```
def check_data(start_date, end_date):
    cols = ['name', 'grade']
    df = spark.read.parquet('path/MyFolder').select(cols)
    df = df.filter(f'date > "{start_date}" and date < "{end_date}"')
    return df
```

The code above is handy and it works fine. However, now I want to add '**height**' and '**date**' columns, and ignore date=20210701 (because it missed two columns). Things got tricker. If I use

```
def check_data(start_date, end_date):
    cols = ['name', 'grade', 'height', 'date']
    nan = 'Nan'
    df = spark.read.parquet('path/MyFolder').filter(f'height != "{nan}"')
    df = df.filter(f'date > "{start_date}" and date < "{end_date}"')
    df = df.select(cols)
    return df
```

I got this Error

```
   Cannot resolve 'height' given input columns  [name, grade].....
```

The only solution I got here is to loop through all parquet folders and then append pyspark dataframe, but that would take extra hours.

Also, if I delete the date=20210701, problem is also solved, but I just cannot do that.

Can you please share your thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is missing for a single row or for a small amount of rows, you can replace the null value with the mean/median value of that column.

In this case you can add calculate median of all the height in parquet and then add that value for date=20210701.

This way your data won't be skewed.

Also median is preferred over mean, because some outliers can skew the mean value.

Comment: thanks for replying. My question is related to coding. i am not worried about skewed or biased statistics at all. First, I need to extract the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution is very simple.

```
  df = spark.read.format('parquet').option('mergeSchema','true').load(path).select('name', 'grade', 'height', 'date')
```